# Overloading C++ Insertion Operator (<<) for a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a class that overloads the insertion operator but in my header file I get the error.

```
Overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)
```

Here is my code:

.h file

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Domino dom);
```

.cpp file

```
ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, Domino dom) {
    return os << dom.toString();
}
```

I'm following a text book and this is what they use as an example but its not working for me.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wasn't it called "bitwise left shift operator"?

Comment: Could you update the question with the entire code if it is not that large?

Comment: `operator<<` cannot be a class member. It must be a friend!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably put your `operator<<` inside a class declaration.  That means it takes an extra hidden parameter (the `this` parameter).  You need to put it outside of any class declaration.

Answer (score 14):

The insertion operator (<<) can be used as a member function or a friend function.

**operator << used as a member function**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os);
```

This function should be invoked as :

```
dom << cout;
```

In general if you are using the operator as a member function, the left hand side of the operator should be an object. Then this object is implicitly passed as an argument to the member function. But the invocation confuses the user and it does not look nice.

**operator << used as a friend function**

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Domino& obj);
```

This function should be invoked as :

```
cout << dom;
```

In this case the object `dom` is explicitly passed as a reference. This invocation is more traditional and user can easily understand the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*insertion and extraction overloading*/
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
   int real,imag;

public:
    complex()
    {
      real=0;imag=0;
    }
    complex(int real,int imag)
    {
        this->real=real;
        this->imag=imag;
    }
    void setreal(int real)
    { 
        this->real=real; 
    }
    int getreal()
    {
       return real;
    }
    void setimag(int imag)
    { 
        this->imag=imag; 
    }
    int getimag()
    {
       return imag;
    }
    void display()
     {
      cout<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i"<<endl;
     }

};//end of complex class

 istream & operator >>(istream & in,complex &c)
     {
         int temp;
         in>>temp;
         c.setreal(temp);
         in>>temp;
         c.setimag(temp);
         return in;
     }
 ostream &operator <<(ostream &out,complex &c)
 {
     out<<c.getreal()<<c.getimag()<<endl;
     return out;
 }

int main()
{
  complex c1;
  cin>>c1;
 // c1.display();

  cout<<c1;
  //c1.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: insertion an extraction overloading without using friend function